# As anyone tried using the below OSM API

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

Please let me know if anyone tried using the below OSM API in C# .Net application to retrieve address from Latitude and Longitude.

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=[Latitude]&lon=[Longitude]

I request to post the same below.

thanks

Comment: whats your code? chances are,you do have to many requests

Answer (score 2):

As the error says you are creating too many requests.

A quick search on google brought up that there is a hard limit on the number of requests you're allowed send, found in the usage poilicy of Nominatim:

> Requirements
>
> - **No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second).**
> - Provide a valid HTTP Referer or User-Agent identifying the application (stock User-Agents as set by http libraries will not do).
> - Clearly display attribution as suitable for your medium.
> - Data is provided under the ODbL license which requires to share alike (although small extractions are likely to be covered by fair
>     usage / fair dealing).

Source: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy

So in order to fix this error you'll have to make sure that you are not sending more than 1 request per second for your whole application.

Comment: Thank you. for trail purpose I am just trying only one request. still the issue remains same.

Comment: You are probably still blocked. Wait until getting unblocked or try to [contact](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact_channels) the [admins](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Admins). Stop abusing OSM services in the future.

Comment: sorry sir. I am not abusing the services or not here to degrade any of the services. I was just mentioning about the issue I faced, so that I can get help from the experts(like you) to get the solution to my problem.

Comment: Not providing a user agent can also cause the problem (see "Requirements"), even on the first request. I had a similar problem using the .NET `WebClient` API, and providing a user agent fixed the problem (e.g. `webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Your Application"`).